# How do I fix Docker getting stuck at "RUN npm run build" with Angular 15

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm

I'm trying to build an Angular 15 project in Docker, but the build always hangs at the `RUN npm run build` step and never completes. This a fresh install `ng new ng-sandbox-15` with the `Dockerfile`, `.dockerignore`, and `nginx.conf` copied from a **working Angular 14 fresh install**.

`./Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:16-alpine as builder

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

# disabling ssl for npm for Dev or if you are behind proxy
RUN npm set strict-ssl false

## installing and Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build
RUN npm ci && mkdir /app && mv ./node_modules ./app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /app

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY . /app/

# Build the application
RUN npm run build


FROM nginx:1.17-alpine
## From 'builder' copy published folder
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 4000

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

`./package.json:`

```
{
  "name": "ng-sandbox-15",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.5.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

As seen in the image below, the Angular build completes successfully in 26.5 seconds, but the step is still stuck 20+ minutes later.

[image: Docker stuck at RUN npm run build]

The most similar problem I've seen is [Docker build getting stuck at npm run build step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70271194/docker-build-getting-stuck-at-npm-run-build-step), and I disagree with the only proposed answer `CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]` because that will not wait for the build to complete before trying to copy the built project into the nginx html directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I face the same issue when updated my angular 13 projects to 15.

I have 4 projects, 2 will build success and 2 will stuck after the `RUN npm run build`. After compare the projects I found out in my case is causing by the analytics inside the angular build.

Change the parameter in `angular.json` from

```
"cli": {
  "analytics": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX",
},
```

to

```
"cli": {
  "analytics": false,
},
```

This solution solved my issue. The root cause may be causing by upload the analytics data are blocked inside docker build

Comment: Excellent! This solved my issue completely. This is probably worth a bug report on the Angular GitHub repo.

Comment: Excellent!! This solved my issue completely as in our pipeline we don't have internet access which cause a huge delay in the build time after the build process hanged

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the copy path it should be `./` not `. /` in the docker file.

Also please look into the below code

1. Installing and storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build:

```bash
RUN npm install && mkdir /app && mv ./node_modules ./app
```

2. Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory:

```bash
WORKDIR /app
```

3. Get all the code needed to run the app

```bash
COPY ./ /app/
```

Comment: Changing the copy path to `./` did not seem to help. The Docker code referenced all work correctly with my Angular 14 project. I've reviewed them, and they look appropriate to me.

Comment: `./` or `.` is the same thing.